# v-carousel skippping whenever it moves to the next item

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Whenever the v-carousel moves onto the next image in the reel it shrinks down before loading the image, causing the carousel to 'skip'. Is there any way to prevent this? Perhaps by pre-loading the images? The static images come from a parent nuxt component using asyncData so I thought it would already be loaded.

The carousel component:

```
<template>
<v-container class="hero-wrapper">
  <v-carousel
    cycle
    hide-delimiters
    height="auto"
    >
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(item,i) in heroImages"
      :key="i"
      class="pb-0 mb-0"
      :href="item.link"
      >
      <img :src="item.image" class="hero-image">
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ["heroImages"]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `eager` prop to `v-carousel-item`.

```
<v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in heroImages"
    :key="i"
    eager
    class="pb-0 mb-0"
    :href="item.link"
>
```